# Oracle/PostgresQL nextval procedure - the simplest realisation

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, sequence, psql

What wrong here? I'm looking the simplest way to realise sequence nextval over true primary key ID, stored into the table

```
DECLARE
smth NUMBER;
LOOP
   smth := (select gen_ns_ces_id.nextval from dual);
   EXIT WHEN smth > (select MAX(ID_NS_WORK) from CES.NS_CES)
END LOOP;
```

> CREATE SEQUENCE  "CES"."GEN_NS_CES_ID"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE
>   9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 1837 NOCACHE 
>   NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;

```
ID    NAME
1845  JONNY
..    ....
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by `realise`?  Do you mean that you are trying to reset the sequence's value based on the largest primary key value in a table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle, I would expect an `into`:

```
select gen_ns_ces_id.nextval into smith
from dual;
```

Comment: `smth := gen_ns_ces_id.nextval;` is also valid starting with Oracle 11.

Comment: to me warning word 'select' as incorrect